# Android Tabbed View Not Updating Until Touch

Tags: java, android, list, azure, touch

I have an android app with a tabbed layout that contains a list view. I'm trying to update the list after retrieving information from a server. However, the list doesn't update until the screen is touched. All of the information is correct, but no matter how long I wait, the list won't populate the screen until I've tapped it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tab1.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by hp1 on 21-01-2015.
 */

//NEW
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    List<Post> postList;
    public static NewAdapter newAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        postList = new ArrayList<Post>();

        try {
            //get data from azure
            mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

            //set lists
            ListView newListView = (ListView) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.newListView);
            newAdapter = new NewAdapter(mainActivity, postList);
            newListView.setAdapter(newAdapter);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        //get the posts loaded asynchronously
        retrievePosts();
    }

    public void retrievePosts(){
        AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    postList= mainActivity.postTable.execute().get();
                    Log.e("TAG",postList.get(0).text);
                    newAdapter.updateList(postList);
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        runAsyncTask(task);
    }

    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> runAsyncTask(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            return task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            return task.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

NewAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class NewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Post> postList;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public NewAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<Post> myPostList) {
        postList=myPostList;
        context=mainActivity;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return postList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        PostCell postCell=new PostCell();
        View cellView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_cell, null);

        postCell.textView=(TextView) cellView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        postCell.textView.setText(postList.get(position).text);

        cellView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+postList.get(position).text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return cellView;
    }

    public List<Post> updateList(List<Post> myPostList){
        postList = myPostList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return postList;
    }

    public List<Post> addToList(Post post){
        postList.add(post);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return postList;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Final Answer** - here is my final code with the problem solved. Bnydev was right about the problem, but there were a few more things I had to change as well.

```
public void retrievePosts(){
        //NOTE: must have a return type for an async task to run onpostexecute, which
        //is executed on the ui thread so the screen can be updated

        AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>(){
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    postList= mainActivity.postTable.execute().get();
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return true;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean reult) {
                newAdapter.updateList(postList);
            }
        };

        task.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tab1.java, you have the method `retrievePosts()`, which contains an AsyncTask. Within `doInBackground()` of this AsyncTask, you call `newAdapter.updateList()`, and within `updateList()`, you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

The documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) says, that `notifyDataSetChanged()` refreshs the UI. But as far as I know, refreshing the UI should only be possible from the UI thread, not from any background thread. You could try to call `newAdapter.updateList()` in `onPostExecute()` within the AsyncTask, see the example [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). `doInBackground()` is executed on a background thread, `onPostExecute()` is executed on the UI thread.

```
public void retrievePosts(){
    AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                postList= mainActivity.postTable.execute().get();
                Log.e("TAG",postList.get(0).text);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute() {
            newAdapter.updateList(postList);
        }
    };

    runAsyncTask(task);
}
```

PS: I don't think that it is good to catch all exceptions without anything like `e.printStackTrace()` etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Your reasoning was right, there were just a few more things you have to do as well. I'll edit my post to also have my final code.